# How to implement a "repaintable" ListView on runtime?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Painting/populating a ListView during `onCreate()` `onStart()` and/or `onResume()` are fairly straightforward.

The tricky part is when you are waiting for asynchronous jobs such as `Volley` and `AsyncTask` because the job has to repaint the contents of the `ListView`.

With that, how should one implement a "repaintable" `ListView` with repainting it from probably separate jobs during runtime?

Comment: listview has notify methods which should notify the adapter that there is new data and populate new items. Do this once you get the data after async tasks

Comment: @Raghunandan I'll try to seek and study those methods. However, it would be better for other readers if you can point specific method names. Thanks, I could go with that for a start.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged() its there are for ArrayAdapter as well.